# Exit BASH script whenever keyphrase is entered

Tags: bash, try-catch, exit

I am having problems with finding how to exit my script when a `keyphrase` is entered: e.g. "Foo".

Essentially I wish to test every user input for this phrase and invoke the exit command. I could create a test function I call after every user entry but this seems inelegant.

I am using function:

```
function EXIT {
    printf "\n\nSCRIPT IS NOW TERMINATING\n"
    if [ -n $userLogged ]; then
            local TIME="$username LOGGED OUT at: "$(date +%r)" on the "$(date +%d/%m/%Y)"\n"
            printf "$TIME" >> usage.db
    fi
    exit
}
```

and:

```
trap EXIT SIGTERM
```

Can it be done using trap?

Comment: I don't see how you can avoid writing something like `case ${userInput} in Foo ) EXIT ;; * ) echo "other processing goes here" ;; esac`. (or the same idea with `if ... elif ... fi` blocks.) Good luck.

Comment: I'm with @shellter I don't see how you can avoid testing input every time you ask for it. You could write your own `read` function which did the testing internally but that's only slightly better (and less obvious) than testing after each `read`/etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure but I guess you are after something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Save this script as "my_exit"

function EXIT {
    printf "\n\nSCRIPT IS NOW TERMINATING\n"
    if [ -n $userLogged ]; then
            local TIME="$username LOGGED OUT at: "$(date +%r)" on the "$(date +%d/%m/%Y)"\n"
            printf "$TIME" >> usage.db
    fi
    exit
}

trap EXIT SIGUSR1

while :; do
    read -p "Enter your test word: " word
    if [ "$word" = "Foo" ];
    then 
        pkill --signal SIGUSR1 my_exit
    fi
done
```

I used SIGUSR1 instead of SIGTERM just to show the functionality better. It's also possible to change that into two separate scripts with minor modifications i.e. "EXIT+trap" block will be one, the eternal loop another and latter one would signal the first one via SIGUSR1 to do exit routines.